# Slice an url with regex - php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to slice an URL but I can not get it to work like what I want to, I am using `parse_url` which returns parts of the URL but not what I am looking for. Is there a function for to do this or must I use regex?

**Sample URL:**

> http://www.example.com/en/some-slug
>
> http://www.example.nl/nl/een-slug

So im trying to get the current parts, **com/en/** or **nl/nl/** and when not match return the first part **com/** or **nl/**. So im trying to get the domain extention + the next path.

```
// Tried this, but not the results that im looking for 

$url = 'http://www.example.com/en/some-slug';

var_dump( parse_url($url) );

// returns this(not wat im looking for

array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(13) "/en/some-slug"
}
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: parse_url, im not good with regex so I hope that there is a better way toi slice the urls

Comment: You should update your question with what you done so far, share your code.

Comment: Define “domain extension”; or at least give an example what exactly you would want to look at for, say, an `example.co.uk` domain.

Comment: Good one, yes .co.uk is also in my domain data...

Answer (score 2):

Use [PHP function parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get all components of a URL

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/dir?data=1';

// Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "/dir"
  ["query"]=>
  string(6) "data=1"
}
```

Comment: See my example, not what im looking for